# Dax calender with holidays for different divisions in different countries, power bi

Tags: date, calendar, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a pretty big calender table made in Dax, with about 40 different columns. I introduced an additional holiday table to make two columns in the calender table: "Holiday" and "IsWorkday". This works fine, but now i have divisions in a different country, and therefor these two columns must be dynamic based on the division.

The tables that are relevant are sales, division, calender and holiday. Calender and division is both related to sales. The holiday table is only used with LOOKUPVALUE in the calender table.

Simplified preview:
[Simplified preview][1]   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQv5G.png

The two columns in the Dax calender looks like this, (where [Date] not from Holiday is the Date from the Calender dax)

```
    "Holiday",                          VAR DivisionCountry = LOOKUPVALUE(Division[Country], Division[DivisionID], SELECTEDVALUE(SALES[DivisionID]))
                                        VAR Country = LOOKUPVALUE(Holiday[Country], Holiday[Country], DivisionCountry)
                                        RETURN
                                        LOOKUPVALUE(Holiday[Holiday],Holiday[Date],[Date], Holiday[Country], Country),
                                        
    "IsWorkday",                        VAR WeekdayNum = WEEKDAY( [Date], 2)
                                        VAR DivisionCountry = LOOKUPVALUE(Division[Country], Division[DivisionID], SELECTEDVALUE(SALES[DivisionID]))
                                        VAR Country = LOOKUPVALUE(Holiday[Country], Holiday[Country], DivisionCountry)
                                        VAR Integer = INT( NOT WeekdayNum IN {6, 7} && ISBLANK(LOOKUPVALUE(Holiday[Holiday],Holiday[Dato],[Date],Holiday[Country], Country) ) )
                                        VAR Result = Integer
                                        RETURN Result,
```

'Holiday' returns blank even when i select different divisions.
'IsWorkday' is able to return 1 for mondays-fridays when i comment out the holiday-part, but returns 0 when i include it. The Holiday-part of the two columns are basically the same.

Im not that good at Dax, and i admit that i probably dont understand the real logic of the dax that i've written here, as my logic clearly fails.

I really appreciate any help or tips to get me closer to a solution. Hopefully the information i have provided is sufficient. If not - please let me know and i will add.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would begin by creating a relationship between `Calendar[Date]` and `Holiday[Date]`. Next, I would create a measure `HolidayName` to return the holiday for a given `[Date]` and `[DivisionID]`.

```
HolidayName = 
    
VAR DivisionCountry = LOOKUPVALUE(Division[Country], Division[DivisionID], SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[DivisionID]))

RETURN

LOOKUPVALUE(Holiday[Holiday], Holiday[Date], SELECTEDVALUE(Calendar[Date]), Holiday[Country], DivisionCountry)
```

Then you could make another measure `isWorkdayOrHoliday` to combine `Calendar[isWorkday]` and the newly made measure `HolidayName`.

```
isWorkdayOrHoliday = INT(Calendar[isWorkday] && ISBLANK([HolidayName]))
```

This would return `isWorkdayOrHoliday = 0` if a given date is either a weekend or holiday.